# Rudin's POMA Chapter 1 exercise 5

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Hi I am writing to check if the proof that I wrote is valid, I feel like it seems kind of right to me but as I am only a beginner in writing proofs I feel like I might've missed something.

Question: Let E be a nonempty set of real numbers which is bounded below. Let -A be the set of all numbers -x, where x is an element of A. Prove that $$ infA=-sup(-A)$$

My solution is as follows,

$\text{Let } \alpha \space\text{be a lower bound of A}$
Then
$\alpha = \inf (A)\space \text{if}\space x\geq\alpha\space\text{for every}\space x\in A\space \text{and there does not exist a }\beta\space \text{where}\space  \beta\gt\alpha\space \text{and} $
$\space x\geq\beta\space \text{for}\space x\in A$

As $x \geq \alpha$ for $x \in A$

then, $-x \leq -\alpha $ for all $-x \in -A$

Since there is no $\beta \gt \alpha$ where x $\geq \beta $ for $x \in A$

Then there is no $-\beta \lt \alpha$ where $-x \leq -\beta$ for $-x \in A$

thus $-\alpha = -\sup (-A)$ and $\inf (A) = -\sup (-A)$

Is it right for me to just assume the existence of a greatest lower bound like that?
Also, what are some good ways to self check my work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, can you use correctly MathJax? Your text must be out the formula `$..$` or `$$..$$`, or you can use `\text{abc}`.

Comment: Did you mean Ru**d**in's?

Comment: @Sebastiano  Thanks for the formatting advice! I tried to reformat it to make it more readable and it was so much faster!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner whoops

Comment: You can change one sentence in your argument. Let $\alpha$ be the infimum of $A$ which means that there is no $\beta>\alpha$... Rest is fine.

Comment: Also a typo in the later part. Write "also there is no $\beta <-\alpha$ such that $-x\leq \beta$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: The assumption of greatest lower bound is fine as $A$ is bounded below. In general for easy problems using the definition is sufficient so you just need to check if your argument matches the definition given. Often learning definition using words instead of symbols is a great help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded below then there exists $M$ such that $a\in A\implies M\le a$ for all $a\in A$. Therefore, $-a\le -M$ for all $-a\in -A$ and so, by the least upper bound property of the real numbers, there exists $U$ such that $U$ is a least upper bound for $-A$.

Since $-x\le U$ for all $-x\in -A$, $-U\le x$ for all $x\in A$ and therefore is a lower bound for $A$. If $L$ is another lower bound for $A$ then $L\le x\implies -x\le -L$ so $-L$ is also an upper bound for $-A$.

Since $U$ is the least upper bound for $-A$, $U\le -L\implies L\le -U$ so $-U$ is the greatest lower bound.

Now $-U= -\text{sup(-A)}=\text{inf(A)}$ so the theorem is proved.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I feel like ur proof was conceptually similar to mine but is there anything I needed to add? is there a necessity in introducing the variables U and L?

Comment: @Burgercrazy Notice that I don't assume the existence of a greatest lower bound.

Comment: ah ok It's clearer to me now. Thank you!

Comment: can i clarify, is it justified to assume a greatest lower bound exists, or is it necessary for that to be proved?

Comment: @Burgercrazy We are given that a lower bound exists. We must prove that the greatest lower bound is what the claim says it is. It is a fact, and a nice exercise, to prove that any ordered set with the least upper bound property has the greatest lower bound property. Our job here was easier because we were given an ordered field.