# Discussing Ex 13. Section 3. p-29, Munkres' Topology 2E.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, order-theory, well-orders

In Exercise 13, section 3 on page 29 of Munkres’ Topology 2E, the problem is stated as follows.

Prove the following:

Theorem. If an order set $A$ has the least upper bound property, then it has the greatest lower bound property.

The following is my attempt to prove the above theorem.

**Proof:**

Let $A$ be an order set that has the least upper bound property.
Suppose $E$  be a nonempty subset of $A$ that does not have the greatest lower bound.

Then, consequently, $ E^c $ the complement of $E$ which is also a nonempty subset of $A$ will not have the least upper bound, contrary to the fact that $A$ has the least upper bound property.

Thus, every nonempty subset of $A$ must have the greatest lower bound.
Thus, we conclude that $A$ has the greatest lower bound property. ∎

I’d like to know whether it is a preferable one or not, and if it isn’t, I’d like to request your counter-part if you don’t mind.

If there is already a similar question, I'd like to keep it as a duplicate one.

Comment: See the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689617/rudins-poma-chapter-1-exercise-5/3690282#3690282).

Comment: The argument with the complement of the set doesn't seem to work. John Douma's proof doesn't work since it relies on negating the set elements, which is not possible in this case. But the above duplicate shows a trick of taking the least upper bound of the lower bounds and showing that it is the greatest upper bound.